# Attention layer in Deep Learning classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to have a normal classification model with a tabular dataset. I came across the Attention layer and I would like to use it to improve my model's accuracy.

```
input_features_size = X_train.shape[1]

layers = [
    tf.keras.Input(shape = input_features_size),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu', name = 'first_layer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu', name = 'second_layer'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'output_layer')
]

metrics = [
    tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'accuracy'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name = 'precision'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name = 'recall')
]

NUM_EPOCHS = 20

deep_learning_model = Sequential(layers = layers, name = 'DL_Classifier')
deep_learning_model.compile(
    loss = binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4),
    metrics = metrics
)
```

I tried adding Addention layer (tf.keras.layers.Attention()) in the layers list but I am doing some mistake here. I am getting this error : Attention layer must be called on a list of inputs, namely [query, value]

How to add an Attention layer?

Comment: The `Attention` layer is not something that you can plug-and-play as a general-purpose solution for any use-case or a model. For example, attention is typically used for data with a time-like axis. I'd say read about `Attention` first understand how it works and maybe have a look at other refs where they use attention for tabular data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @thushv89 I thought we can plug it in directly like other layers. Looks like i need to do some reading. Thanks again

Comment: @JSVJ, as mentioned in the error, the attention layer takes a list of tensors as input. It seems like you are not passing the proper input and hence the error. Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention) for more information. Thank you!